# Vue 2 package inside Vue 3 project (this.$set is not a function inside package)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, package.json, pivottable.js

I'm having some issues with a package that uses Vue 2 inside my Vue 3 project (issue happened on 3.0.0. and also on 3.2.37 when updated).
Package:
https://github.com/Seungwoo321/vue-pivottable
Uses:
`"vue": "^2.6.10",`

When I try to integrate this component inside my project, it doesn't work and console logs `this.$set is not a function` inside `PivottableUi.js?4d01:252:1` i.e. the imported package.

It seems like `$set` was removed from Vue 3 so I'm wondering if I can fix this problem in any way other than copying and fixing the code of the component.

I would like to use this component so I don't have to implement [PivotTable.js](https://pivottable.js.org/examples/) (vue-pivottable is vue implementation of it( directly since it will make my workload smaller and I don't need add more dependencies.

Comment: The only thing you can try is `@vue/compat`. Otherwise, fork it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use Vue 2 packages with Vue 3. You may fork it and make compatible by yourself.